# Unable to Update and Delete an Object from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm working on a project in Angular with Firebase. I am unable to Update and Delete an object from Firebase Database.

Here is an [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/updating-and-deleting-an-object-from-firebase?file=src/app/app.component.ts) representing my issue.

**component.ts**

```
update(course) {
    this.db.object('/courses/' + course.key ).update(course.value + 'updated');
}

delete(course) {
    this.db.object('/courses/' + course.key ).remove();
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group mt-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter cource..." (keyup.enter)="add(course)" #course>
</div>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" *ngFor="let course of course$ | async | keyvalue">{{course.value}} <span><button (click)="update(course)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success mr-2">Update</button><button (click)="delete(course)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'unable'? Is there an error in console logs? Are the rules in the firebase console (.read and .write permissions) set up wright?

Comment: I got this "Error: Reference.update failed: First argument must be an object containing the children to replace." and i have set read & write permissions to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to `snapshotChanges` to get the actual key for the document, which you can refer to when updating (I use `set` here, since it doesn't require an object) and deleting. So change how you are getting the data. Usually I add the payload data with spread operator, but since your payload is just a string, I added it as a variable `payload` (you can choose your own name) and store the document id as `key`:

```ts
this.course$ = this.courses.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map((changes: any) => {
    const data = changes.map(d => ({ key: d.key, payload: d.payload.val()}))
    return data;
  })
)
```

Then you can use the correct key to update and delete:

```ts
update(course) {
  this.db.object('/courses/' + course.key).set(course.payload + ' updated');
}

delete(course) {
  this.db.object('/courses/' + course.key).remove();
}
```

Then we need to make some changes to the template, we don't need the `keyvalue` pipe:

```html
<li *ngFor="let course of course$ | async "> {{course.payload}} </li>
```

Your forked **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/updating-and-deleting-an-object-from-firebase-neanlt?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Also do not use `any`, type your data, makes your life so much easier!!

Answer (score 0):

The `update()` method takes a JavaScript **object** with key-value pairs.

But in this call you are instead passing a single string value, which is not valid:

```
this.db.object('/courses/' + course.key ).update(course.value + 'updated');
```

The fix depends on what you store under `/courses/$key` in the database.

---

If your structure under `/courses/$key` is an object, and looks like this:

```
"courses": {
  "coursekey": {
    "property1": "value",
    "property2": "value"
  }
}
```

You can update a specific property with:

```
this.db.object('/courses/coursekey').update({ property1: 'updated' });
```

---

If your structure under `/courses/$key` is an single value, and looks like this:

```
"courses": {
  "coursekey": "value"
}
```

You can update it with:

```
this.db.object('/courses/coursekey').set('updated');
```